# Receiving custom parameter in retrofit callback

Tags: java, android, rest, callback, retrofit

This is my `post` :

```
@POST("/path")
@FormUrlEncoded
void postIt(@Field("id") String id , Callback<Response> response);
```

and this is the `Callback`:

```
 private Callback<Response> responseCallBack = new Callback<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
        // get the id 
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // do some thing
    }
};
```

### Question:

in the `callback` i want to receive the id which posted in `@POST`, how should i do that?

and i can't change the server API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do this we need an abstract class

```
abstract class CallBackWithArgument<T> implements Callback<T> {
    String arg;

    CallBackWithArgument(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    CallBackWithArgument() {
    }
```

and make an instance

```
new CallBackWithArgument<Response>(id) {
        @Override
        public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
            //do something

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //do something

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You can simply make Callback to hold requested id and create new callback every time

```
class MyCallback extends Callback<Response> {
    private final String id;
    MyCallback(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
        // get the id 
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

So when you call service

```
myService.postIt("777", new MyCallback("777"))
```